# Sitecore MultilistField.Remove() is not able to remove items from selected list

Tags: sitecore-api

My Code is something like this

```
MultilistField multilistField= item.Fields["FieldID"];
 foreach (var item in multilistField.GetItems())
    {
        if (multilistField.Contains(item.ID.ToString()))
       {
            //Code is not going inside, not able to understand why
             multilistField.Remove(item.ID.ToString());
         }
}
```

When I checked values in Field, I can see value with guid id in lower case without braces ({})
something like this

`48afc299-9218-4187-a912-d7272698b163` while `item.ID.toString()` is in `{48AFC299-9218-4187-A912-D7272698B163}`.

Answer (score 0):

After getting your code on my local and testing the scenario, I found that the reason maybe you have not selected anything in your `Multilist Field`.

The statement `multilistField.GetItems()` will give you the number of items that you have selected from your `Multilist Field`.

And when you run this statement

```
 multilistField.Remove(item.ID.ToString());
```

It will give you the error below.

```
Sitecore.Exceptions.EditingNotAllowedException: 'Item '/sitecore/content/Home/New test Page' is not in editing mode. Item ID: {56305117-8C9C-4C08-96D5-BB97A8E27419}'
```

For that, you have to use `BeginEdit` and `EndEdit`.

Refer to this link to learn how to remove items from `Multilist Field`.

https://sitecore.alexiasoft.nl/2007/08/29/remove-an-item-for-a-multilist/

Answer (score 0):

Below code helped me in solving the issue. So basically Multilist field is having some D Type guids and it was not getting removed.

`````
MultilistField field = item.Fields["fieldId"];
 foreach (var multiListItems in field.GetItems())
                            {
                                var dTypeGuid = multiListItems.ID.ToGuid().ToString("D");
                                if (field.Contains(dTypeGuid))
                                {
                                    field.Remove(dTypeGuid);
                                }
                                else if (field.Contains(multiListItems.ID.ToString().ToUpper()))
                                {
                                    field.Remove(multiListItems.ID.ToString().ToUpper());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    field.Remove(multiListItems.ID.ToString());
                                }
                            }
````
`````

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `BeginEdit` and `EndEdit` to remove items from Multilist Field

```
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
      itm.Editing.BeginEdit();
      
     // You can write your code logic here 
      Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multiListField = 
      itm.Fields[“multiListFieldName”];
      multiListField.RemoveLink(item.ID.ToString());
     
     itm.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
```

You can refer this link as well for get more information about place an item in editing mode https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/place-an-item-in-editing-mode.html

Hope this helps you.